# How can I modify a text file using VBA and maintaing the format of the existing text lines

Tags: vba

How can I modify a text file using VBA, without losing the the format of my text lines - I'm talking about lines which have at least 1 number on it
For example: If I have 5 numbers on a line, in the new modified file, all of those number are on 5 rows. 
The lines which contains characters other than numbers are fine!

Please, if you have 3-4 minutes, open any single text file using VBA (containing a line with at least 2 numbers on it) and try to save it to a new file, using the method posted below.

```
Open Path For Input As #1 
Do Until EOF(1)     
Input #1, ReadData
File.WriteLine (ReadData)
```

The problem :The format of the lines with numbers is not preserved.

Original:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Modified:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of file are you processing?

Comment: What do you mean not preserved?

Answer (score 1):

Writeline writes a line (with a line feed).
You will have to assemle a full line and then write it into a file:

```
dim s as string
s=data1 & " " & data2 & " " '...
file.writeline(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Input is designed to assign values to individual variables.  Like a record of comma-separated values.

Try Line Input,

```
Open Path For Input As #1 
Do Until EOF(1)     
Line Input #1, ReadData
File.WriteLine (ReadData)
```

[more info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264130%28v=office.15%29.aspx)